# ProcessUserAuthorization in Google OAuth2.0 is throwing 400 error

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I'm having an issue with a line of code in c# to make a OAuth2.0 request. The code is like this:

```
            WebServerClient consumer = new WebServerClient(CGmail.serverGmail, CGmail.clientIDGmail, CGmail.clientSecretGmail);
            consumer.ClientCredentialApplicator = ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter(CGmail.clientSecretGmail);
            IAuthorizationState grantedAccess = null;
            try
            {
                    grantedAccess = consumer.ProcessUserAuthorization(Request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {   
            }
```

the line `grantedAccess = consumer.ProcessUserAuthorization(Request);` is throwing the following error:

[image: error]

This was working fine until yesterday, I haven't done any change to this functionality. Does anyone know what could happend?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We also suddenly had this problem. I suspect it had something to do with Google changing some of their [OAuth2 endpoints](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration) or [deprecating some scopes](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#deprecated-scopes). Still not terribly sure what caused it to break specifically.  I couldn't get DotNetOpenAuth to work with any changes to scopes and endpoints, but i'm admittedly not an expert in OAuth2.

To fix it, we just used [Google.Apis](https://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth2-gmail-imap-web-applications) instead of DotNetOpenAuth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Casually we are implementing Google.Apis but we haven't finish yet, so after we implemented i'll mark this answer as correct, we think this is the alternative solution.

Comment: So don't we have any other options other than using Google Api's?